# return custom query as an activerecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wrote this custom query, which I don't think can be converted nicely using active record query interface:

```
SELECT * FROM dockets 
INNER JOIN entries 
ON entries.docket_id = dockets.id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
  SELECT 1 FROM entries AS e 
  WHERE e.docket_id = dockets.id 
  AND e.docket_type REGEXP 'Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4' 
)
```

I can execute this query using `connection.execute`:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM dockets INNER JOIN entries ON entries.docket_id = dockets.id WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM entries AS e WHERE e.docket_id = dockets.id AND e.docket_type REGEXP 'Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4' )"
Docket.connection.execute(sql)
```

The problem is does not return an ActiveRecord::Relation. It gives me a MySQL::Result object. Therefore I cannot append relation methods to it:

```
Docket.connection.execute(sql).limit(10)
NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for #<Mysql2::Result:0x007fcd1dde6330>
```

Is there another interface I can use to return an ActiveRecord::Relation object so I can continue to append relation methods to it? And if not, what other options do I have?

Comment: you are checking that you want records whose docket_type is not having this regex 'Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4'..right?

Comment: @test I am to retrieve all dockets and their associated entries, where none of the associated entries contains the regex 'Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4'. That means if all entries of docket do not contain it, then I want both docket and entries. If an entry does contain it, then I do not want either docket or entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
Docket.joins(:entry).where(Entry.select('1')
     .where("entries.dockect_id = dockets.id")
     .where("entries.docket_type REGEXP 'Key1|Key2|Key3|Key4'")
 .exists.not)
```

Comment: @xdazz when I convert this to sql, it gives me the following: SELECT `dockets`.* FROM `dockets` INNER JOIN `entries` ON `entries`.`docket_id` = `dockets`.`id` WHERE (NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `entries` WHERE (entries.docket_id = dockets.id) AND (entries.docket_type REGEXP 'Key1|Key2|Key3|Key3')))). Will this still produce the same results with those additional parantheses?